# VSCode Python Debugger stops suddenly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

after installing Windows updates today, debugging is not working anymore.

This is my active debug configuration:

```
"launch": {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "DEBUG CURR",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "justMyCode": false,
      "stopOnEntry": false,
    }...
```

When I start the debugger, the menu pops up briefly for 1-2 seconds. But then it closes. There is no output in the console.

It does not stop at set breakpoints.

Does anybody have the same problem? Is there a solution?

#### System settings

- OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise (10.0.17763 Build 17763)
- VSCode version 1.64.0
- Python version: 3.8.11 (in the active Anaconda Environment)

Installed VSCode extensions:

- Python (Microsoft) version: v2022.0.1786462952
- Pylance (Microsoft) version: v2022.2.0

Comment: It seems, the problem is known. But there is no solution...

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18453

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/724858/vscode-debugger-not-working-for-python.html

Comment: Solution found. See my answer...

Comment: I'd say this is rather a workaround, not a solution. In any case, appreciate it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's an issue with the latest Python Extension for VSCode.

Downgrading the python extension to v2021.12.1559732655 fixes the problem.

[image]

Comment: The newer version `2022.8.1` also works for me. The breaking version seems to be `2022.10.0`.

Comment: `2022.14.0` has this bug. Downgrading to `2022.8.1` works.

Comment: I had the same problem today with Python Extension v2022.16.1 using Python 3.6 (I'm still on Ubuntu 18.04). It seems that the VS Code debugger doesn't play nicely with [older versions of Python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19559), so I installed Python 3.8 using [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). VS Code debugger now works like a charm.

Comment: unfortunately going to 2022.8.1 did not solve the issue for me

Comment: this seems to be happening again in 2024

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue with the python plugin v2022.20.2

Going back to 2022.8.1 resolved it for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

2022.20.1 also has this issue. Went back to 2022.8.1 and it works just fine.